# Smart GWT purchasing license.

Tags: smartgwt

I currently use GWT and wanted to clarify if smart GWT is free for commercial use or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sanika, SmartGWT is available as both free and paid versions such as SmartGWT LGPL, SmartGWTEE, SmartGWTPro and SmartClient. This [link](http://www.smartclient.com) may help you decide the version you should go with.